# rails user_post_path(post.user.user_name, post) is missing required keys: [:user_id] doesn't work on posts index page but works on welcome page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i got a little annoying problem.

i use this line of code on my homepage and it works, but on my posts/index page it doesn't work.

```
<%= link_to post.title, user_post_path(post.user.user_name, post), class:"post-listing-home-title" %>
```

Ultimately i want to render all posts from users on the post index page, linking to their post assosicated like this

localhost:3000/users/user_name/posts/"name of the post"

here is my error

Showing /Users/****/rorapps/*****/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #10 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>"eli-the-great", :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_id]

here is my code

**Posts controller**

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc")

  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
      @post = current_user.posts.build

  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
      @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save

        flash[:notice] = "Post successfully created"
        format.html { redirect_to @post }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)

        flash[:notice] = "Post successfully created"
        format.html { redirect_to @post }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
        @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content,:slug, :metadescription, :focuskeyword)
    end
end
```

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1 class="post-listing">Listing Posts</h1>

    <% @posts.each do |post| %>


            <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime('%A, %B %d') %></p>

  <%= link_to post.title, user_post_path(post.user.user_name, post), class:"post-listing-title" %>

        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

    <% end %>
```

**welcome.html.erb** again this is where the line of code works

```
    <div class="container">

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <div class="featured-post fadeInBlock animated">

        <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime('%A, %B %d') %></p>
        <span class="show-right"><%= link_to '', user_post_path(:user_id, post), class:"myright fa fa-chevron-right" %></span>

      <%= link_to post.title, user_post_path(post.user.user_name, post), class:"post-listing-home-title" %>

       <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_post_path(:user_id,post) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_post_path(:user_id, post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div id="about-home">

    <div id="about-box">
      <h1 id="abouttext">Try Harder !</h1>

  </div>



</div>
```

Thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
<%= link_to post.title, user_post_path(post.user.user_name, post), class:"post-listing-title" %>
```

You are render these links inside a loop

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

So its seems like one of your post author doesn't has user_name.

Comment: How should i fix it, because that link works on the homepage ? and i can see the username within the url